# How to update MongoDB document with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, database

I have a mongoose schema for a mongodb collection which I define as follows:

```
var userSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {type: String, unique : true},
  password: {type: String},
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  sketches: [{name: String, sketch: Array}]
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

In the database collection, I currently have a document that contains values for all attributes except `sketches` for testing purposes. I have a server endpoint that when called should make a PUT request to update the document and add an object to the sketches array:

```
app.route("/addSketch/:username").put(function(req, res) {
  var user_name = req.params.username;
  User.findOne({username:user_name},function(err,foundObject){
    if(err){
      console.log("error");
      res.status(500).send();
    }
    else{
      if(!foundObject){
        res.status(404).send();
      }
      else{

        if(req.body.strokes && req.body.sketchName){
          var sketchObj = [];
          sketchObj[req.body.sketchName] = req.body.strokes;
          foundObject.sketches.push(req.body.sketchData);
        }
        foundObject.save(function(err,updatedObject){
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send();
          }
          else{
            res.send(updatedObject);
          }
        });
      }
    }

  });


  console.log('saving on server');
   var form = formidable.IncomingForm();

   console.log(form);
   console.log('the type of the request received is', (typeof req));

  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text/plain"});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
    var name = fields.name;
    var newSketch = new SavedSketch();
      newSketch.name = name;
      newSketch.sketchData =  fields.value;
      newSketch.save(function(err,savedObject){
        if(err){
               console.log(err);
               res.status(500).json({status:'failure'})
            }
            else{
              console.log("ID: " + fields.value.id + " strokeData:" + fields.value.strokes);
               res.json({status: 'success'});
            } 
      });

         res.end();
  });
  });
```

In this web service, I'm essentially trying to select the User document by the username which is passed as a parameter to the url string like the following:

```
http://localhost:11235/addSketch:testname
```

For some reason, when I try to make a PUT request using postman with the following body, I get a 404 error:

```
{"sketchName" : "tempName", "strokes":[1,2,3,4,5]}
```

The document itself contains the following data:

```
{
    "lastname" : "name",
    "firstname" : "test",
    "password" : "password123",
    "username" : "testname",
    "_id" : ObjectId("57c4d7693aa85cea2acf4d4d"),
    "sketches" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

**Is there an error in the logic of the web service itself that is preventing the document from being found?**

Answer (score 1):

404 is Error not found, it means that route is not available.

Change your url to this:

```
http://localhost:11235/addSketch/testname
```

You will not get 404 error after this. i hope this helps.

**Edit: Solving 500 Error issue**

you are pushing the object in wrong format in the sketch array.

**replace :**

```
var sketchObj = [];
sketchObj[req.body.sketchName] = req.body.strokes;
foundObject.sketches.push(req.body.sketchData);
```

**With:**

```
foundObject.sketches.push({"name" : req.body.sketchName,"sketch" :req.body.strokes});
```

this should solve your 500 Error.

Comment: 500 Error is internal server error, now you need to check where in your route, it breaks. Use console.log() at different points in your backend code,and find out at which point it is breaking. Then you can ask another question if you cant solve that error. As far as this question is concerened, its solved.